# How good is the Paracord 550 as an electrical insulator?

Tags: soldering, cables, pins, insulation, conductivity

So [following wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parachute_cord) the Parachute cord 550 is made from nylon Kernmantle rope, however [this site](https://www.paracord.eu/paracord/paracord-550/550-polyester-paracord) where I sourced the cables from says that it is made of a Polyester sleeve (outer layer) and a core of Nylon draden.

[People are using](https://www.overclock.net/forum/261-artisan-sales-forum/1621381-paracord-mice-cable-made-ceesa.html) it for cable sleeves, but I want to be sure how good of an insulator it is. My use case is basically the above, using it as a cable sleeve to mod a mouse and make the cable basically more flexible and lighter, however my cable route for my mouse is below the circuit board so the mouse button which is basically an Omron switch has it's soldered pins there (6 of them in like a 1 cm square region) and it will be basically touching the cable. Here is a picture of it:

[image]

Should I cut the paracord shorter to start just before it leaves the mouse where no pins are located, or there is no problem leaving it likes this? Not many mice route it below the circuit board where it touches and contacts  pins, however I am assuming that it would've been already thought about accidental touchings. So my biggest gripe is that I am not sure if the materials used are good conductors.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good insulator but not sealed, so it can be punctured easily by sharp tips.

Strain relief and a large bend radius is also important.

Comment: I was thinking to put a heatshrink at the pins though, but since both materials are good insulators PVC or paracord, I guess it does not matter. For the strain relief, large bend (not sure if that much large is needed) would do something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7d5Zb1r3BM Not sure why two heatshrinks are used in the video, as it is already secured before leaving the mouse where the clear one is used.

Comment: Strain Relief should be 3 to 5x stiffer than wire and 4 x diam. bend radius (EST.)  to strengthen exit wire that bends,  2 heat shrinks help as strain relief

Comment: Would you argue that the video is suggesting insufficient amount of all of that? We go out of the topic, but the heatshrink of the input wire, if you check the videos - some times it is applied 50/50 or 70/30 paracord/wires, sometimes on the paracord only, what is your opinion on that?

Comment: Just looked .video has a good bend radius 4~5Diameter